# Rotate Headers 45 Degrees

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Need to create ag-grid with rotated column headers at a 45 degree angle.  The column should be wide enough for a checkmark.

I tried using the example provided for here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-header/#textOrientation

The plunker doesn't work for Angular and the sample code does not load.

The CSS provided in example does not display the entire header. Header is limited to 25px in height. The header is at a 45 degree angle, but can only see a few letters. I also tried to use the setHeaderHeight() and headerHeight, neither one provided any positive result.

What I'm looking to have is something similar to what is seen here: https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/

Currently using: 
Angular 7 
ag-grid-angular 21.2.2
ag-grid-community 21.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your table is contained in an angular component. Try to wrap the styles that you want to apply with a ng-deep directive like this:

```
::ng-deep {
    .your-style {
    }
}
```